# how to hide particle emitter but not particles

Tags: rendering, particles

Whenever I render out my particle sim, the particle emitter renders out as well. I've tried to disable it during renders using the camera icon in the *Outliner* view, but that disables the particles as well. **How do I hide the particle emitter but not the particles?**

Answer (score 1):

In the *Particle systems > Render tab*, uncheck *Emitter*.

[image]